# Suppressing save dialog on iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I have an iframe and its src is set to a pdf file. The iframe is hidden and I use it to print a pdf file when a user clicks a button on my html page then pdf file is supposed to print.

Everything works fine on chrome , but on firefox and ie it shows a save dialog for the pdf file as soon as the page is loaded. How can I suppress this.

Comment: go to about:config in FF, there you can change it. The problem is  that it is standard for FF and as far as I know, you can force chrome from your website to download it too but you can't prevent FF to download it

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If a browser is configured to save PDF files instead of opening them in a plugin, then there is nothing you can do about that.